# custom event declaration

Tags: vba

Can an event declaration have an optional argument?  For example:

```
public event MyEvent (Optional MyArgument as string)
```

I tried it with no success, and I wanted to make sure that this, in fact, is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they can't.
Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/event-statement:

> You can declare event arguments just as you do arguments of procedures, with the following exceptions: events cannot have named arguments, **Optional** arguments, or **ParamArray** arguments. Events do not have return values.

Comment: Good stuff, just went through it.  Thank you!